# Applescript method to control order of tabs in merged Finder windows

Tags: applescript

Trying to find the Applescript method of controlling the order of tabs in a merged Finder window. I am using this script to merge folder windows:

```
tell application "System Events"
    click menu item "Merge All Windows" of menu "Window" of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1 of application process "Finder" of application    "System Events"
end tell
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: when merging windows in tabs, the order is based on windows order. the front windows is the right tab and the window in deep background on left tab. all other in-between depending of their focus. So before merging, you must change the order of the windows themselves.

Answer (score 0):

As @pbell mentioned you should sort your windows before merging them. Here is a little snippet sorting three opened windows (Desktop, Applications, Documents) that shows how it could work for you.

```
set windowsFromBackToFront to {"Desktop", "Applications", "Documents"}
repeat with aWindowName in windowsFromBackToFront
    tell application "Finder"
        try
            set index of window aWindowName to 1
        end try
    end tell
end repeat

tell application "System Events"
    click menu item "Merge All Windows" of menu "Window" of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1 of application process "Finder" of application "System Events"
end tell
```

That should be a good starting point for you. Should be easy to change the script to match your finder windows.

Regards, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: This is not working for me, Michael. The script does change the order of the tabs as I move the window names around, but they don't reliably end up in the order I'm specifying. What did work (yesterday) was to open them in a "cascade" arrangement where the upper left corner is inset down and to the right of the previous window. Then when I merge, they end up in the same order. I'm unclear how the FInder actually does decide to order them when it merges windows.